# Google Maps Iframe Embed Not functional on bootstrap/foundation

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, zurb-foundation

Google maps trouble centering the location when img is set to max-width. There's a solution, which is to put

```
#map_canvas img {
max-width: none;
}
```

This doesn't seem to work for me though, because I'm not using the Javascript API, so there doesn't seem to be a map_canvas. I'm simply embedding using iFrames.

When I try to add a div around the iframe, and set the parameters, I still get the same result.

I'm not sure what to write/append to make google maps iframes play nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an interactive map iframed in or a static google map image which you are iframing?

If you are using an interactive google map using an iframe you'll need to be sure to declare the 'center' property inside of the map variables. Unfortunately the map will only center when the initial load of the page is made, which means if you load the page at a large resolution and then scale down the map will be off-center since when the map was created the center was defined at a different location (refreshing at a smaller resolution fixes this.)

### For Interactive Google Maps

```
// Google Maps
var map;
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 17,
        draggable: true,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.913914,-94.637427), // this one
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
```

### For Static Google Map Images

when declaring the image src it should look something like this:

```
<img src="maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=46168&zoom=11
&size=300×300&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false" alt="google map" />
```

All you do is change a few values and you can position this map anywhere you’d like.

**Centering Options**

- City/State: Plainfield, IN
- Zipcode: 46168
- Address: 1917 Hawthorn Drive, Plainfield, IN
- LatLong: 39.77,-86.16